# If multiple services are run withing one Tomcat server is how is this implemented?

Tags: tomcat

Does each service get a separate process? Is everything done within the same JVM? Is there a way to see how much memory is devoted to each service?

EDIT: If one process, does Tomcat run the individual services in different threads?

Comment: There is one process, one JVM, separate classloaders. Too broad.

Comment: you can run several Tomcats or just one, in all case of course they have multiple threads.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: I was asking about multiple WARS deployed within the same Tomcat server.

Comment: You can edit your question and make it more clear - there is no such "service running within Tomcat", never.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: multiple WARS is the key: are all the WARS running within same process or can they be made to run within different processes or different threads by tomcat configuration?

Comment: In all case, one Tomcat instance = one process. One Tomcat server uses many threads for different things, as all JVMs do. If you are willing to change the default behaviour, you need to read the documentation, particularly [Executor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/executor.html) and [Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). About memory, if you need to allocate dedicated space to one application this means you need several JVMs running, which means : several Tomcats.

Comment: By the way this question is in no way related to programming, you didn't show any line of code.

Comment: @EugèneAdell: where is a better place to ask questions about things like this?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. I bet [sf] would be the right place, as your question is more about the server internal behaviour than a coding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Tomcat server runs as a single process. When it accepts a new connection, it allocates a thread to process that connection from start to finish.

Each web application (WAR) is deployed using a unique *context root*: so if you have URLs `http://localhost:8080/app1` and `http://localhost:8080/app2`, you know that they are different applications based on the context root.

Within each web application, Tomcat maintains a routing table that says which class should be invoked for a given URL. If you're using servlets, it might say that `/mypage` is routed to `com.example.MyPageServlet`, while `/myotherpage` is routed to `com.example.MyOtherPageServlet`.

Each servlet class is an instantated object. So, the first thing that Tomcat does after accepting a request is to figure out which web-app it belongs to based on context root, and which servlet object in that web-app should handle the request. Then it invokes the service method on that object.

To keep web applications independent, each application is loaded using its own [classloader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html). This means that the `app1` instance of `MyPageServlet` will the implementation of `com.example.MyHelperClass` that was bundled with the `app1` WAR, and not the one bundled with the `app2` WAR. For the most part, this is an implementation detail that you don't have to care about.